# Debian is saying that i'm out of space when ever i try to install or remove packages

Tags: linux, debian, apt, hard-drive, aptitude

here's the return from df:

```
~$ df
Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/debian-root    321041   310074         0 100% /
udev                        10240        0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                      405168      788    404380   1% /run
tmpfs                        5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                      810320        0    810320   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                  233191    46249    174501  21% /boot
/dev/mapper/debian-home 459851880 16424688 420044972   4% /home
/dev/mapper/debian-tmp     368615   364485         0 100% /tmp
/dev/mapper/debian-usr    8516872  4877496   3183696  61% /usr
/dev/mapper/debian-var    2817056   577944   2076296  22% /var
```

as you can see debian-root is all full but debian-home has not been used at all. how can i fix this?

btw, the error that i'm getting is as follows:

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: @user2985853 You *might* be out of inodes in your file system.  Try removing unneeded files and retry.

Comment: /tmp folder is full as well, which you need target first to empty in fact

Comment: What does `mount | grep /var` show? Having separate partition with lots of free space on it which is seemingly there to hold `/var` does not mean it really is mounted there.  Sorry for the somewhat silly comment but it's better to double check.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your / (root) and /tmp folders are full and / is way way too small.  You've got to delete things on /tmp and / so you have maneuvering room to do something, that something being deleting packages to give you breathing room to migrate everything to a system with sane partition sizes.

And leeduhem, moving /usr under /home will do no good.  It's broken out as a partition and has plenty of free space.